# Apache spark directories

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark, I am observing that after spark program completes there are directories getting created and their names are like:

spark-3505c49a-0402-41ce-8187-c82ea7527e15
blockmgr-37b4b5e6-a97c-4779-9658-a19c194b9a2c

Please help me to understand about these directories, why are they getting created?

Answer (score 0):

These are temporary directories. The `spark-` prefixed directory is used for multiple purposes, one of which is the [ShuffleManager](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/shuffle/ShuffleManager/) and  `blockmgr-` prefixed directories is used by the [BlockManager](https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/storage/BlockManager/).